# The imperative tone of Stack Overflow ads on Facebook may be off-putting

Tags: discussion, advertising, facebook

While scrolling down my Facebook feed I noticed the following SO ad:

[image]

I find the ordering tone employed ("Tell us **now**", "Take the survey **now**") somewhat condescending, so I thought I'd send this feedback.

As someone interested in advertising, I have this question:

Has this tone helped in getting more conversions?

(If so, I might even end up using it myself!)

Comment: Just as an FYI, the "ordering tone" is often referred to as ["imperative mood"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I was not familiar with the term

Comment: You will **not** assume the tone of text.  I am **not** being condescending.

Comment: What would you expect it to say instead? "Tell us later"? "Tell us"? "Consider telling us"? "You can tell us if you want"?

Comment: I don't read that as them "ordering" us to go take the survey.  I simply read that as "click here to go take the survey now", only without adding a lot of extra words.

Comment: If you click on an ad, isn't it implied that you will do what's requested "now"? My question is: is the word "now" added at the end of the sentences helping in conversions, or if it's actually deterring them because of what some people might construe as a "condescending tone"?

Comment: To your question about advertising, I can state from experience that this does make a difference. I've experimented with AdWords campaigns where I A/B tested slight changes in wording and tone. There were large, statistically significant increases in clickthrough rates on ads providing a direct call to action ("take the survey now") versus those that were just descriptive ("the survey is available"). Even "take the survey" vs. "take the survey now" would probably have noticeably different clickthrough rates. I didn't expect that at all.

Comment: @BradLarson - The implication of "now" is that there's a time limit. If the survey is just available then I can always do it later. If I'm being told to do it now, that implies it might not be around later. That assumption can go away if a company insists that *everything* has to happen "now" but it's appropriate to use here since the survey does have a deadline.

Comment: @BradLarson That's very interesting, and it fully addresses my question. Thanks!

Comment: As one of the many who ignores advertising (and other meaningless things), my response is 'meh'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When confronted by armed men with attack dogs at midnight in a dark, foggy alley, "take the Emacs developer survey now!" might indeed sound condescending, and much worse.

A banner ad, on the other hand, like a TV ad, is  an environment where it is understood that there's no way to issue *actual* commands - after all, the recipient does not have to fear any consequences when they don't follow them.

Hence, to me,  the tone reads as a friendly *invitation*, not a command.

I'm willing to bet a beer that that's most people's interpretation.

Comment: Based on the downvotes to this question, you might be right! Thanks for your response

Comment: @FranciscoHodge that's why emoticons were invented to help people know the tone of the sentence but in this instance, no add is going have an ordering tone it would be so counterproductive, no one would click the ad.